# Finding XPath with the text that is below a closed tag

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have the following HTML. I need to get the XPath using DOWN as a keyword.

```
<span>
    "DEVICE: some random values that I'm not bothered about"
    <span class="c-emoji_plain_text">:sensor_1000_4_1:</span>
    "/interfaces/:/interfaces/:mib2d], TRIGGER: interface_status, MESSAGE: 
    $interface_name is DOWN"
</span>
```

The problem I'm facing here is, when I use the following XPath, it's not recognized:

```
//span[contains(text(),'DOWN')]
```

I see that the text above child span is used but not the text below it.

Kindly help.

Comment: your `DOWN` text is not in the `span`, what's the parent tag?

Comment: Thanks Anderson for editing. Couldn't save the edits as he had already edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
//span[contains(text(),'DOWN')]
```

with

```
//span[contains(.,'DOWN')]
```

to select required `span` node

Note that such selector can match several elements. To make it more specific you can use

```
//span[span and contains(.,'DOWN')]
```

This will match `span` that contains `span` child node as well as `"DOWN"` substring

Also

```
//span[contains(text()[2],'DOWN')]
```

should do the trick

Comment: Its not working. What's the role of the dot(.) here?

Comment: In this case it stands for *complete string value of span*. Can you elaborate a little about *not working*? Show how you used it in code

Comment: I will be using selenium library of Robot framework to automate this.
Hence the the line would look something like this:
Click Element    xpath://span[contains(text(),'DOWN')]

Comment: In case you need to select dynamic element which is absent in page source, but generated by JavaScript, you might need to implement some kind of *"waiting for element"*

Comment: Yes, this is a dynamic element. Accurately, i'll be using it this way: **wait until page contains element xpath://span[contains(text(),'DOWN')]timeout=60s**